# how to match a sentence at the end of line?

Tags: c#, regex

```
const string input = "===== Action: [Action1]  State: [State1] by:[user1] at [timestamp1] =====    [Notes1]===== Action: [Action2]  State: [State2] by:[user2] at [timestamp2] =====    [Notes2]";

Regex expression = new Regex(@"===== Action: (?<Action>.*?)State:(?<State>.*?)by:(?<userid>.*?)at(?<timestamp>.*?)=====(?<Note>.*?)");

var results = expression.Matches(input);
foreach (Match match in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine("UserId:" + match.Groups["userid"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Action:" + match.Groups["Action"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("State:" + match.Groups["State"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("TimeStamp:" + match.Groups["timestamp"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Note:" + match.Groups["Note"].Value);
}
```

I was able to parse all the values correctly except Note. Any ideas what I did wrong?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Can we have a definition of your Requirement, and/or Expected output vs actual output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to use `(?======|$)` at the end of your `regex`..`(?<Note>.*?)` in your regex would match everything till end which is not what you want..

So the regex would be

```
===== Action: (?<Action>.*?)State:(?<State>.*?)by:(?<userid>.*?)at(?<timestamp>.*?)=====(?<Note>.*?)(?======|$)
```

Use `SinglelineMode` option if the input is separated by newline

Answer (score 1):

My psychic debugging sense tells me that the `.*?` at the end of your regex isn't greedy, and will only pick up 0 spaces(which satisfies the `.*?`).

I think you might want to work in some symbol into both your input and your regex to identify where the end of the `Note` should be

Comment: I don't think it will return any characters at all (as `.*?` should match "as few as possible of any number of characters, including 0")